# How to invoke code on same thread the request started

Tags: c#, multithreading, asp.net-web-api, newrelic

I have a POST controller method using async await in a lot of services and in the controller level I need to send some New Relic parameters.
New Relic gives warning logs when parameters are sent from a thread other than the requests started.

> NewRelic WARN: Agent API Error: An error occurred invoking API method
>   "AddCustomParameter" - "System.InvalidOperationException: The API
>   method called is only valid from within a transaction. This error can
>   occur if you call the API method from a thread other than the one the
>   transaction started on.   at
>   NewRelic.Agent.Core.Api.AsyncAgentApi.GetCurrentTransactionBuilder()
>   at NewRelic.Agent.Core.Api.AsyncAgentApi.AddCustomParameter(String
>   key, String value)"

How can I invoke the code that send the parameter value to New Relic in my controller method?

Example, the below code in the controller.

```
var threadid = Thread.CurrentThread.ManagedThreadId;
Log.Debug($"Before async method : {ThreadIdMessage(threadid)}");
var reportObject = await ReportService.GetReportAsync(requestModel).ConfigureAwait(true);
if (reportObject.PolicyModels != null)
{
    threadid = Thread.CurrentThread.ManagedThreadId;
    Log.Debug($"Before sending New Relic values: {ThreadIdMessage(threadid)}");
    AddPoliciesCountInNewRelic(reportObject.PolicyModels.Count);
    AddTotalTransactionsCountInNewRelic(
                            reportObject.PolicyModels.SelectMany(p => p.PolicyTransactionModels).Count());
    threadid = Thread.CurrentThread.ManagedThreadId;
    Log.Debug($"After sending New Relic values: {ThreadIdMessage(threadid)}");
}
```

Will print

```
DEBUG - Before async method : Current Thread Id: 5  
DEBUG - Before sending New Relic values: Current Thread Id: 9
NewRelic.AddCustomParameter(CVPoliciesCount,2)
NewRelic.AddCustomParameter(CVTotalTransactionsCount,8)  
DEBUG - After sending New Relic values: Current Thread Id: 9
```

Per New Relic warning log I should invoke the `AddCustomParameter` method in thread id 5.

`AddPoliciesCountInNewRelic` and `AddTotalTransactionsCountInNewRelic` calls the `ApiControllerBase.AddNewRelicParameter(string, string)` base class protected method.

```
private void AddPoliciesCountInNewRelic(int policiesCount)
{
    AddNewRelicParameter("CVPoliciesCount", policiesCount.ToString());
}

private void AddTotalTransactionsCountInNewRelic(int transactionsCount)
{
    AddNewRelicParameter("CVTotalTransactionsCount", transactionsCount.ToString());
}

protected void AddNewRelicParameter(string key, string value)
{
    if (!string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(key) &&
        !string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(value))
    {
        try
        {
            NewRelic.Api.Agent.NewRelic.AddCustomParameter(key, value);
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            Log.Error($"ERROR! : New Relic Parameter Exception {ex}");
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: https://discuss.newrelic.com/t/are-custom-params-supported-in-async-mode/37601 < they claim async controllers are now supported.

Comment: `ConfigureAwait(true)` in asp.net does not guarantee you get back to the same thread that started the call like it does when you are working with a UI thread in Winforms or WPF.

Comment: In fact `ConfigureAwait(true)` is the default behaviour. It's exactly the same as if `await ReportService.GetReportAsync(requestModel);`.

Comment: The code doesn't show any calls to NewRelic. Please post code that shows how you create the transaction and how you call `AddCustomParameters`. Could the message be correct? *Is* there an active transaction?

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos the code is updated how I call the AddCustomParameter. I don't set any transaction but I see that New Relic has a bucket for me based on the method of the application. And it looks like it's working now! Also, New Relic logging of the warning stopped.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was able to work around the problem with using continuation but like @evk commented in @Tim answer, New Relic should account to fix this so that we don't have to workaround proper code to meet such requirement.

```
    var context = TaskScheduler.FromCurrentSynchronizationContext();    
    var threadid = Thread.CurrentThread.ManagedThreadId;
    Log.Debug($"Entry ThreadID: {threadid}");
    var getReportTask = ReportService.GetReportAsync(requestModel);
    getReportTask.ContinueWith(antecedent =>
    {
        var continuationThreadid = Thread.CurrentThread.ManagedThreadId;
        Log.Debug($"continuationThreadid: {continuationThreadid}");
        var result = antecedent.Result;
        if (result.PolicyModels != null)
        {
            AddPoliciesCountInNewRelic(result.PolicyModels.Count);
            AddTotalTransactionsCountInNewRelic(
                result.PolicyModels.SelectMany(p => p.PolicyTransactionModels).Count());
        }
    }, context);

    var reportObject = await getReportTask.ConfigureAwait(false);
```

It will print as expected the same thread id.

```
DEBUG - Entry ThreadID: 5 
DEBUG - continuationThreadid: 5
```

Comment: In this case, why not use the *synchronous* version of the API? This way you won't run the risk of another request taking your thread and forcing you to wait for it. PS - in ASP.NET the synchronization context is *not* the thread. You may *still* get a different thread.

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos and you do. I tried it out myself and the continuation was not on the initial thread. The SynchronizationContext is of AspNetSynchronizationContext which if you lookup the source code of the post method it results in using the TaskScheduler.Default [source](https://referencesource.microsoft.com/#System.Web/AspNetSynchronizationContext.cs,f0184c54fac66559)

Answer (score 0):

If you must get back the same thread, then you really can't exit that thread-- there is no guarantee that your thread will ever come back to you.  Async ... await will restore the *context* of your action request correctly, but not necessarily the same thread.

In other words, either don't make async...await calls and keep your thread, or kick off your async code in your controller method but and block and wait for it to finish (and thus defeat the purpose of async..await code, since you won't be yielding the thread for another action method while you wait for your IO to complete)

Comment: Or file an issue to the NewRelic and ask them to fix their code.

Comment: @evk exactly...can't beat my programming due to their requirement.